# How to create a user without a profile on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, user-profile

Can anyone tell me how to create a local user without a profile on Windows 7?

I have a cron job I want to run, but I do not want this user to to show up on the list of local logins on the startup screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To hide additional user accounts on Windows & Logon Use Regedit (also works for Vista)

1. at Run type regedit
2. Once in regedit go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
3. In the left panel, right click on Winlogon and click New and click Key.
4. Type SpecialAccounts and press Enter
5. In the left panel, right click on SpecialAccounts and click New and click Key.
6. Type UserList and press Enter.
7. In right panel of UserList, right click on a empty area and click New then click DWORD (32bit) Value.
8. Type in the name of the user account that you want to hide and press Enter.eg: Everyday Account.
9. In the right panel, right click on the user account name and click Modify.

To hide the user account – Type 0 and click OK. Whenever you want to use the account just unhide it by typing 1 instead of zero.